# How to run hudi on dataproc and write to gcs bucket

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, apache-hudi, dataproc

I want to write to a gcs bucket from dataproc using hudi.

To write to gcs using hudi it says to set prop fs.defaultFS  to value gs:// (https://hudi.apache.org/docs/gcs_hoodie)

However when I set fs.defaultFS on dataproc to be a gcs bucket I get errors at startup relating to the job not being able to find my jar. It is looking in a gs:/ prefix, presumably because I have overridden defaultFs which it was previously using the find the jar. How would I fix this?

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1617963833977_0009 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1617963833977_0009_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2021-04-12 15:36:05.142]java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found : gs:/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1617963833977_0009/myjar.jar
```

If it is relevant I am setting the defaultFs from within the code.
sparkConfig.set("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", gs://defaultFs)

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting `fs.defaultFS` to GCS when creating the cluster. For example:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create ...\
   --properties 'core:fs.defaultFS=gs://my-bucket'
```